# English (US) - English (intl., with AltGr dead keys) not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, language-support, internationalization

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.

During OS installation I selected and tested English (US) - English (intl., with AltGr dead keys), and then the combination of **ALTGR + n** was working as expected: I got **ñ**.

But now Ubuntu is installed, the international version was not set and I can't find this version of English listed in the keyboard layouts.
The list includes the following:
[List of english options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsLxW.png)

Also I tried:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
Choose > Generic 105-key PC (intl.)
Choose > English (US)
Choose > English (US) - English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)
Choose > Right Alt (AltGr)
Choose > No compose key
```

And also tried in the last step: Choose > Right Alt (AltGr)

But none of them seems to be working.

Do you have any ideas of how can I set the international layout?

**EDIT**

**As @GunnarHjalmarsson answered, by clicking English (US) more options are displayed.**

Comment: Click _English (United States)_ for more options.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson thank you, so much that was enough to find the option I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost missed the answer by Gunnar in the comment. So here again for anybody with the same issue:

click add input source

[image: Add Input Source]

then click on English (United States). Afterwards more options appear:

[image: More Options]

cheers

Comment: yes i did that. but it doesnt work!

Comment: ╮ (. ❛ _ ❛.) ╭ What do you mean does not work? Afterwards you can click on 'en' symbol on the dock in the upper right corner to choose the keyboard layout that you have just installed...

Comment: in some windows the dead keys simply dont work. In others it does. thats why its so frustrating.
I keep on running into this issue again and again. I think its some browser windows but didnt make a list yet.
and i only use ONE keyboard layout!!!

Comment: Ah. That's annoying. I suppose you could raise issues with the application's issue tracker and see if they can fix it. Linux on Desktop is not always flawless, unfortunately.

Comment: This blatantly does not answer the question. The question is for "US International (AltGr dead keys)". The screenshot does not show that option. It does show how to change your layout, but the specific question on how to find "US International (AltGr dead keys)" is not answered in the slightest.

Comment: 6th from the top ;) my good friend @Joeytje50

Comment: @DrD Incorrect. That is "with dead keys", not "with AltGr dead keys". There is a crucial difference: If you're trying to type something like `cd ~/Downloads`, the 'with dead keys' one needs you to type "~[SPACE]/Downloads` (which is quite annoying and kills the flow of typing), whereas the 'with AltGr dead keys would just work like any keyboard without dead keys (you can just type "~/Downloads". The point is: AltGr deadkeys ONLY act as deadkeys when you explicitly tell it to become dead keys (namely, when you press `AltGr`+`~` and then `n`.

Comment: Works on 22.04.